# Add each Alias in separate file

Tags: windows, apache, httpd.conf

I have manually installed Apache 2.4.6 on Windows for my development environment (I don't like WampServer or EasyPHP).

I want to have a separate file for each of my Alias directories, I don't want to edit httpd.conf directly each time I need a new Alias. How can I set it up so that I can include a whole directory of files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Include`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#include) can include wildcards:

```
Include c:\your\dir\*.conf
```